# Creating a loop for a code replacement from a column in R

Tags: r

I want to copy and paste this several times but instead of the "code" included in the example, I want to include the value stored on a column from a xlsx dataset.
This is my starting point (R script):

```
r <- POST(paste(url_base,service,method,sep="/"),

body = paste("{'entity':'sigpac', code: 'imported_file$code' }",sep=""),

add_headers(.headers = c("Content-Type"="application/json","authorization"=token)))
```

So in 'imported_file$code' is where I  want to define the loop to repeat everything but for differents rows of the column.

For example this would be a deriable result.

```
[{
            "entity":"sigpac",
            "code":"18188-7-81-11-1",
            "status":"ON"
    
    },{
    "entity":"sigpac",
    "code":"18142-20-237-0-1",
    "status":"ON"


},{
        "entity":"sigpac",
        "code":"181232-20-237-0-1",
        "status":"ON"}
},{
            "entity":"sigpac",
            "code":"1315432-20-237-0-1",
            "status":"ON"}
```

(etc...)

As you see, only the parameter `code` is the one that I wanna change.

I remade the question in order to clarify. THanks for the help Im learning!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
imported_file <- data.frame(code = c("18188-7-81-11-1", 
                                     "18142-20-237-0-1", 
                                     "181232-20-237-0-1",
                                     "1315432-20-237-0-1"))

mystring <- paste('{\n\t"entity":"sigpac",\n\t"code":"', imported_file$code, '",\n\t"status":"ON"\n}',sep="",collapse=",")

cat(mystring)
```

Comment: I tryed to do this and it shows up something similar to what I wanted. But the result doesnt show up witht the proper line up and spaces, is there any way that the result shows up like this?

`},{
        "entity":"sigpac",
        "code":"181232-20-237-0-1",
        "status":"ON"}`

(LIke i put on the example). Thank u a lot btw, it really helped me.

Comment: @Gordenbúh You can use \n to add new lines and \t to add tabs. I've edited my answer to include these for you.